# How to create a projection widget programmatically in orchard cms?

Tags: widget, orchardcms, projection, orchardcms-1.8

I have created a query in my module with this code:

```
var myName = "something" 
var theQuery = _contentManager.Create("Query"); 
theQuery.As<TitlePart>().Title = myName + "Query"; 
var filterGroupRecord = new FilterGroupRecord(); 
var filterRecord = new FilterRecord() 
{
    Category = "Content", Type = "ContentTypes", 
    Description = myName , Position = 1, 
    State = "<Form><Description>" + myName 
          + "</Description>    <ContentTypes>" + myName + "</ContentTypes></Form>"
}; 
filterGroupRecord.Filters.Insert(0, filterRecord); 
theQuery.As<QueryPart>().FilterGroups.Clear(); 
theQuery.As<QueryPart>().FilterGroups.Insert(0, filterGroupRecord);
```

And I know to create a projection widget I should use below code :

```
var theProjectionWidget = _contentManager.Create("ProjectionWidget"); 
theProjectionWidget .As<WidgetPart>().Title = myName + "ProjectionWidget"; 
theProjectionWidget .As<WidgetPart>().RenderTitle = false; 
theProjectionWidget .As<WidgetPart>().Zone = "Content"; 
theProjectionWidget .As<WidgetPart>().Position = "1"; 
theProjectionWidget .As<WidgetPart>().LayerPart.Name = myName;
```

**But I don't know how to assign the above query to this new projection widget.** 
How to assign query id to ProjectionPart.QueryLayoutRecordId???!!

I would appreciate any help.

These are links to this discussion in codeproject & codeplex:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/876128/How-to-create-a-projection-widget-programmatically

https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/580735

Comment: I have to ask: why? Wouldn't it be a million times easier to just query on the content manager from a custom widget?

Comment: This is a custom module too and I also create my content type programmatically so I should do it in this way. Am I right? I think this can be a billion times easier if we have a documentation. And I know you have done your code perfectly but I can't read your mind dude. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Just trying to help, but apparently you're doing just fine.

Comment: We need your help anyway. Best Regards Bertrand

Comment: Projections were never designed to be built programmatically: they are easy ways for administrators to build and lay out queries without writing code. Effectively, you had to create a content item, records, etc. At runtime, the system will need to load your projection and reconstruct the query, which is added overhead. Contrast that with building a very simple part with a simple driver that calls `Query` or `HqlQuery` on `ContentManager` and get right to the business of querying the database. That's especially true in the case of your very simple query.

Comment: Thank you bertrand. I'm confused. I think I should explain my module more. I want to create a module for content categorization. For example for product content part. When admin clicks on "Create new category" link and enters the name , the system creates a content type with that name that has the product part attached and also it creates the related page, the related layer , the related query and the related projection widget in that layer with that query automatically.

Comment: How is that different from Taxonomies?

Comment: Really Bertrand?!   Do you mean the taxonomy module creates a layer and a page and a projection widget and a specific .cshtml file for each term in a taxnonmy piece automatically?!!  I want to ease the hole process for admins. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It doesn't create a layer, but so shouldn't you. It does create a landing page (but not a page content item, which is good) for each term, and for the taxonomy. It doesn't create a projection, but you don't need one, as the taxonomy module has those pages already prepared for you, and if that's not enough, also has APIs to query it. As for a specific cshtml file, yes, it does create alternates. Also, even if what the module brings out of the box is not enough for you, there are publish and update hooks that you can tie into to extend it instead of rewriting it.

Answer (score 0):

After some wrestling with code and debug I found solution for my question.
Anybody with my problem can use this code:

```
theProjectionWidget.As<ProjectionPart>().Record.QueryPartRecord = new QueryPartRecord(){

            ContentItemRecord = theQuery.As<QueryPart>().ContentItem.Record,
            FilterGroups = theQuery.As<QueryPart>().FilterGroups,
            Id = theQuery.As<QueryPart>().Id,
            Layouts = theQuery.As<QueryPart>().Layouts,
            SortCriteria = theQuery.As<QueryPart>().SortCriteria

        };
```